# Send a JWT with every page load

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but the way I have my server set up now is the user send a POST request to /api/login with their username and password. If it's correct, the server send back a JsonWebToken and the client stores it in localStorage by doing localStorage.setItem('auth', token)

Now my question is how do I get the client to send that token to the server every time they go to a new page on the site?

Eg say in the HTML I have

```
<a href = '/home'>Home</a>
```

How do I sent the token when they click that link so the server can validate the user and load the appropriate HTML? I'm using NodeJS and Express

Comment: There is no way for a page to specify HTTP request headers other than for requests made using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: So say I want to have a page that can only be accessed if you supply a token, how can I do that?

Comment: You can use cookies to solve that, but you will have to change your backend implementation.

Comment: Would you know where I can find more info on using cookies for this?